Why does the same field seem to have 2 different API names, one with __c and one with __pc?
This is on the Account object, and is referencing a Contact Id.
I see to different field names when searching for the field in object manager.
Before clicking on the field it is Contact_Id**__pc**
After clicking on the field it is Contact_Id**__c**
I understand that __pc is for person account fields and __c is for custom fields, but I've never seen the same field display 2 different API names. I'm not sure which I should expect to use when running queries, if both names should work, if the name to use should change pending the context.
Why does this field seem to have 2 names? Which one should I use?



The field is Contact_Id__c when querying a contact, and Contact_Id__pc when querying an account. This is because the field is on the Contact object, which gets mirrored as __pc on the Account.
